# AngularJS controller won't load into partial

Tags: angularjs, controller, config

I'm trying to create a login/signup site in order to learn how to separate controllers and partial views, but I'm not sure why my 'LoginController' isn't being injected. Feel free to provide any other feedback.

app.js

```
angular.module('Registration', ['ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider', ($routeProvider) => {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/login', {
      templateUrl: 'app/login/login.html',
      controller: 'LoginController'
    })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login' });
}]);
```

LoginController.js

```
angular.module('Registration')
.controller('LoginController', ['$scope', ($scope) => {
  $scope.message = 'Does this work?';
}]);
```

login.html

```
<div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
{{ message }}
</div>
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="Registration">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Sup?</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app/app.js"></script>
  <script src="app/login/LoginController.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('./public'));

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Listening on port 3000.');
});
```

[Directory Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqSJr.png)

Comment: What do you see in console when you move to /login?

Comment: TypeError: Function.prototype.bind.apply(...) is not a constructor

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you can't use an arrow function in the controller! Totally didn't mean to answer my own question.

Found the answer here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14814

Answer (score 0):

Just try to reach to your login route like http://localhost:8080/#/login